# Rearranging tables in R

Tags: r

For the data set, there are two storage conditions, one at 24hr and one at 48hr. The lipid concentration at each of these storage conditions are measured.

The data is currently arranged like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBngH.png

But I need to re-arrange it to this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qetyq.png

What code do I need for this?? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit your question to include your data as reproducible code, not images. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, note in my sample data we need to provide a `values_fn` argument to aggregate where we have multiple values.

First we need to `pivot_longer` to get all the values in one column, then we can pivot back wider to put hours in their own columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("Lipid")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = value, values_fn = sum)

data <- data.frame(
  treatment = c("24hr", "24hr", "24hr", "48hr", "48hr", "48hr"),
  Lipid1 = c(10, 12, 9, 25, 28, 23),
  Lipid2 = c(15, 18, 14, 30, 33, 29),
  Lipid3 = c(20, 24, 19, 35, 38, 34)
)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  name   `24hr` `48hr`
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Lipid1     31     76
2 Lipid2     47     92
3 Lipid3     63    107
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I am very grateful as I am very new to R and coding!

Comment: Instead of having the sum of each lipid, how would you list each of the values in a separate row? I need to perform a t.test on these two groups(24hr to 48hr, for each lipid), therefore I believe the data needs to be in the specific format shown in link 2?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
data %>% pivot_longer(matches("Lipid"))
```

If you need `name`to be numeric, add this to the pipe:

```
%>% 
  mutate(name = as.numeric(str_extract(name, "\\d")))
```

Comment: Glad it worked. On SO, people help for the reward that comes with helping AND, to be honest, for the credits they get. So, kindly consider accepting this answer and/or upvoting it.